# Error: Permission denied to access property "navigator"

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
package automationFramework;
import java.awt.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; 
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import java.lang.IllegalStateException;

public class Second_Practise {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        String URL = "https://accounts.google.com/signin";
        WebDriver driver;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\geckodriver-v0.14.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        driver =new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get(URL);
        WebElement Email = driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId"));
        Email.sendKeys("dialogspp");
        WebElement Next = driver.findElement(By.id("identifierNext"));
        Next.click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='password']/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")));
        WebElement Password = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='password']/div[1]/div/div[1]/input"));
        Password.sendKeys("dialogapp");
        WebElement PassNext = driver.findElement(By.id("passwordNext"));
        PassNext.click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        //WebElement gmail = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='https://mail.google.com']"));
        WebElement myDynamicElement2 = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@href='https://mail.google.com']")));
        myDynamicElement2.click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        WebElement myDynamicElement3 = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@gh='cm']")));
        myDynamicElement3.click();
    }
    }
```

I am using this piece of code to send an email, but on clicking "Compose" button i am getting the exception. i.e.

```
Jun 20, 2017 2:57:37 PM org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions findElement
WARNING: WebDriverException thrown by findElement(By.xpath: //div[@gh='cm'])
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate an element using By.xpath: //div[@gh='cm']
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '86a5d70', time: '2017-02-16 07:47:51 -0800'
System info: host: 'ANUM-PC', ip: '172.16.11.162', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.lambda$findElement$0(ExpectedConditions.java:896)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.findElement(ExpectedConditions.java:895)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.access$000(ExpectedConditions.java:41)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:205)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:201)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:234)
    at automationFramework.Second_Practise.main(Second_Practise.java:35)

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: Error: Permission denied to access property "navigator"
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '86a5d70', time: '2017-02-16 07:47:51 -0800'
System info: host: 'ANUM-PC', ip: '172.16.11.162', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{rotatable=false, raisesAccessibilityExceptions=false, marionette=true, appBuildId=20161031133903, version=, platform=XP, proxy={}, command_id=1, specificationLevel=0, acceptSslCerts=false, browserVersion=47.0.2, platformVersion=6.1, XULappId={ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}, browserName=Firefox, takesScreenshot=true, takesElementScreenshot=true, platformName=Windows_NT, device=desktop, firefox_profile=UEsDBBQACAgIACp31EoAAAAAAAAAA...}]
Session ID: b216dfb9-b672-4cd2-b7cc-087c74789afa
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:127)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:93)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:42)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:163)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:274)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.isDisplayed(RemoteWebElement.java:315)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.elementIfVisible(ExpectedConditions.java:302)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.access$100(ExpectedConditions.java:41)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:205)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:201)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:234)
    at automationFramework.Second_Practise.main(Second_Practise.java:35)
```

I am able to access the element using firepath but error is still been there. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there any frame?

Comment: Yes , Clicking Compose button open a frame.

Comment: I tried this code. I am able to open compose frame after clicking on compose button.

Comment: @Ankur,
Which selenium version are you using and which browser have you tried?

Comment: I am using selenium 3.4.0 and tried with firefox.

Comment: This issue occurs randomly. You can try with chromedriver

Comment: Let me know if that works